# Authenticate using JWT: Should I always check user existence?

Tags: rest, jwt

Should I always check user existence in the process of authenticating? How if users deleted the account while they still have their API KEY containing user id? It can mess up some part of the system that involve the user.

Comment: can you delete their api key when they delete their account? you can then check if the api key is valid rather than the user exists. Presumably there is already a check to see if the api key is valid. If it doesn't exist because they've deleted their account (and therefore api key), it can't be valid

Comment: @codebrane I've thought about this before. I'm worrying that the API Key could not be deleted due to external troubles like network connection which if server's response can't reach the client device it means the API can't be deleted. But I'm just thinking  to quickly delete the API Key in frontend's side regardless of whether the server successfully deleted the account or not. Is it a good idea?

Comment: it doesn't matter about the client. As long as the server knows the api key no longer exists it can block the requests